# Zu + Inf referring to the first part of the sentence

Tags: infinitive

I would like to translate the following sentence to German.

> I think that the requirements for students are neccessay to be high

Is it possible that the "sie hoch zu sein" refers back to the first part of the sentence like this?

> Ich denke an den Anforderungen an den Schülern, dass es notwendig ist,
>   sie hoch zu sein.

Comment: May I ask what your mother tongue is? Not only the german sentence has an awfully wrong grammar and sentence structure, but also the english sentence seems to be a bit strange.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically incorrect

Comment: You can ask of course, although I don't really see how that would help answering the question or at least proceed with it a tiny bit for that matter. Do you need to be a native speaker of either german or english to get an answer here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In German:

> Ich denke, dass die Anforderungen an die Schüler notwendigerweise hoch sein müssen.

Comment: With "an", don't you have to use Dative? Like an Schülern?

Comment: Well, you could use Dative, but then you would use the plural and say: "Anforderungen an den Schülern". But usually you would just say "Anforderungen an die Schüler".

Comment: @DoktorDonger That's wrong. The phrase _Anforderungen an die Schüler_ is already plural, but accusative. It must not be dative here!

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: Of course, you are right; thank you for the correction!